# Навигация в webview-приложении

Tags: java, android, webview

Ребят, помогите. В общем смысл такой. Сейчас у меня есть код

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/spatial_anomaly/1.html");
```

для загрузки определенной страницы и все там как надо в одной активити настроено. Думаю делать несколько активити таких это тупо, поэтому прошу помочь написать так, чтобы у меня, скажем, была кнопка, которая при запуске стартовала эту активити, отсылая ей адрес страницы, которую нужна загрузить, а другая кнопка соответственно другой адрес

Делаю так потому, что у меня не полностью на вебвьюве прога, а меню будет с помощью java сделано

Comment: Не ясно в чём проблема. У вас уже есть код загрузки HTML. Вызовите его по нажатию на кнопку. Если у вас с этим проблемы - то тогда надо спрашивать про то как на кнопки слушатели нажатий вешать и WebView тут не причём.

Comment: вы наверно не так поняли, все прекрасно грузится. Дело в том, что у меня программа как сборник мануалов, в которой будет меню на java, а сам контент в html-страницах. И мне надо из этого меню открывать. И не хочется делать несколько одинаковых активити для каждого пункта меню, хочется, чтобы была одна активити, а адрес подставлялся в зависимости от того какой пункт будет выбран

Comment: Вам надо, видимо, запускать одну и ту же активити, передавая ей в `extras` ссылку. В самой активити вытащить ссылку из Intent и передать в WebView